# Randomly removing an element from a list by use of a list comprehension

Tags: python

I have an issue with removing elements randomly by using a list comprehension. Each individual element should be randomly removed depending on the probability. So this would mean, if the probability would be 0.2, the average amount of elements that still would exist is 80%. The code should return all remaining elements.

The viruses are the elements and mortabilityProb is the probability or randomness factor.

```
def kill(viruses, mortalityProb):
    return "".join(["".join(random.sample(viruses, int(len(viruses[i])*(1-mortalityProb)))) for i in range(len(viruses))])
```

I am trying to get a better understanding what I am doing wrong. The requirement is that this should be done through a list comprehension.

Thank you in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: What is the error? Add a sample test case as well

Comment: I was trying to follow these guidelines as stated in: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions This function is part of a much larger assignment which I did not post. I am sorry if I have violated any rules or guidelines.

Comment: You have not, everything's fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How a list comprehension can be used to "remove" elements (technically you create a new list without the elements):

```py
# general
[item for item in iterable if condition]

# example to get only the lowercase letters
[char for char in "aBcDeFhGi" if str.islower(char)]

# example filtering out based on probability
# random.random() returns a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1
import random
[item for item in iterable if random.random() > 0.8]
```

I assume you need something like this:

```py
def kill(viruses, mortalityProb):
    return [virus for virus in viruses if random.random() > mortalityProb]
```